# instagram api rate limit clarification

Tags: instagram-api

We make GET requests to the `/users/self/media/recent` and `/media/media-id/comments`
endpoints.
For this we use user authentication with access_token.

According to the rate limit documentation of instagram we should have 5000 requests / access_token / hour available.

logging the number of our requests on average we do about 600 - 800 requests for a user of us but still receive an api limit reached error in the instagram response.
not only that but according to the error we do ~70K request/hour

> You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 68100 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 5000 requests per hour.

Am I missing something? Only a few customers of us are affected by this problem.

Are the limits per user global and all apps the user uses have to share the 5000 requests / hour? That is the only explanation I can come up with but found no documentation of this behavior.

Comment: You may be best contacting instagram api support (https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/)

Answer (score 1):

Post the code, may be you are doing something wrong and its making multiple calls.

The API response header shows how many remaining calls after each API call:

```
x-ratelimit-limit:5000
x-ratelimit-remaining:4998
```

check this value after each call from your code and analyze.